# Simulating Round-Robin scheduling in C

Tags: c, multiprocessing, operating-system

So, I was trying to simulate my own scheduling algorithm in C (in this case, simple round-robin scheduling), whilst essentially overriding the system-default scheduler for those programs. If it helps, I am only interested in the scheduling logic for two processes (created via two `fork()` calls).

The problem, put simply is: *Schedule processes `P1` and `P2` from a parent process, via Round-Robin scheduling with time quantum `q`*

I was using a call to `kill()` and `SIGSTOP`/`SIGCONT` as the primary way for the parent process to suspend and continue the two processes `P1` and `P2`, but for some reason, the OS scheduler still continues to schedule the processes after they've been signaled with `SIGSTOP`. Here is a minimum-reproducible example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pthread.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int n = 10;
float currTime = 0;
float timeQuantum = 2;
pid_t pids[2];



typedef struct RRKeep{
  bool lastProcess;
  long long int lastSwitched;
} RRkeep;

RRkeep RRGlobalState = {1, 0};

long long current_timestamp() {
    struct timeval te;
    gettimeofday(&te, NULL); // get current time
    long long milliseconds = te.tv_sec*1000LL + te.tv_usec/1000; // calculate milliseconds
    // printf("milliseconds: %lld\n", milliseconds);
    return milliseconds;
}

void readFileWriteShm() {
  while(1)
    printf("This is the reader process\n");
}

void readShmWriteMultOp() {
  while(1)
    printf("This is the writer process\n");
}

void* RRscheduling() {
  // Should tell when to switch and which process to switch to
  while(1) {
    while(current_timestamp() - RRGlobalState.lastSwitched < timeQuantum);
    long long int tmp = current_timestamp();
    printf("%lld\n", tmp);
    kill(pids[RRGlobalState.lastProcess], SIGSTOP);
    kill(pids[!RRGlobalState.lastProcess], SIGCONT);
    RRGlobalState.lastProcess = !RRGlobalState.lastProcess;
    RRGlobalState.lastSwitched = tmp;
  }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  pids[0] = fork();
  if(pids[0]) {
    readFileWriteShm();
  }
  else {
    pids[1] = fork();
    if(!pids[1]) {
      pthread_t timer;
      pthread_create(&timer, NULL, &RRscheduling, NULL);
      pthread_join(timer, NULL);
      while(wait(NULL) > 0);
    }
    if(pids[1]) {
      readShmWriteMultOp();
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

So, my question is, how can I stop the OS scheduler from "interfering" in this case, and schedule the programs exclusively using my own scheduling algorithm?

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: By implementing your own threads and real schedulers that can switch the context of threads and save their state or a similar mechanism to context-switching in which the scheduler saves the task states and variables for each task.

Answer (score 0):

You have your PID tests backwards. `if(pids[0])` is true in the parent (since `fork` returned a PID for the child to the parent) and is false in the child (since `fork` returned zero to the child). Yet, if it is true, you execute code you intend for the child.

Similarly, `if(!pids[1])` is true in the child and false in the parent, yet, if it is true, you execute code you intend for the parent.

Comment: That was an embarrassing mixup. The code works as intended after making the change! Thank you so much for your input!